# How To Generate Full DML T-SQL Command For Alter Table in Designer Window?(Include DATABASE INSERT, etc)

Tags: sql-server, triggers

at first my Problem is Solved By Audit.

```
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Audit_Pay_Tables]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [Payrole_Security_Audit]
ADD (DATABASE_CHANGE_GROUP),
ADD (DATABASE_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP),
ADD (SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP),
ADD (DELETE ON DATABASE::[AdventureWorks2017] BY [dbo]),
**ADD (INSERT ON DATABASE::[AdventureWorks2017] BY [dbo]),**
ADD (UPDATE ON DATABASE::[AdventureWorks2017] BY [dbo])
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

But I Want Do This By Trigger on Table.
And I Do Bellow Steps:

Step 1: `Create Trigger For DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS`

Step 2: `Alter Table In Designer Window`

Step 3: SQL Engine Generated 5 Command Bellow:

1. `CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_TableName  ... .`
2. `ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_TableName  SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)`

   **[Missing Command? (I Want That): INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_TableName (Col1, Col2, ...)    SELECT Col1, Col2, WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)] .**
3. `DROP TABLE dbo.TableName.`
4. `EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_TableName', N'TableName', 'OBJECT'   .`
5. `ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD CONSTRAINT  ... .`

[Missing Command?]: How Capture Bellow DATABASE INSERT Command In DDL OR DML Trigger?
INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_TableName (Col1, Col2, ...)    SELECT Col1, Col2, WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)]
Tahnks a lot.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: If you understand the Audit part. I Want Create a DDL OR DML Trigger To Generate Full Script Include INSERT INTO Table. If You Try Modify a Column in Table Designer Window, After Save Trigger Do Not Capture Insert Into Temp Table.